# How to get rid of "Empty Path is not valid " Error while using MySQL with C#.Net

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, mysql-workbench, picturebox

I am developing an application, where I use an update records form,to update data of a particular employee.If I press update button without changing any data of that employee,than an error comes for the picturebox control that "Empty path is not valid",while already an image is present in database for that record.But when I click picturebox control and upload the same image again than no error is given.This is a serious bug in my program.Kindly help me to get rid of it.

```
 imageByte = null;
                FileStream fStream = new FileStream(this.imagePathTextBox.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fStream);
                imageByte = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fStream.Length);

 private void EmployeePictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imageChangedLabel.Visible = false;
            try {
                OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFile.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|ALL FILES (*.*)|*.*";

                if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string pictureLocation = openFile.FileName.ToString();
                    imagePathTextBox.Text = pictureLocation;
                    EmployeePictureBox.ImageLocation = pictureLocation;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }`

   dbCommand1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@img", imageByte));
```

Comment: How you set the path of the picturebox ? what's the path of file? Do you set the ImageLocation property?
Maybe the path is Empty, did you try set a path fixed to test in your application ?

Comment: Yes I am using ImageLocation property and when I first save image in database and upload image to picturebox control then ImagePath is pasted in a textbox control below it and then I copy that path from that textbox control into ImageLocation but using update feature of my application,If  I donot need to upload image than It gives above defined problem.

Comment: Providing an example of the code giving you the issue can go a long in helping you solve the problem.

Comment: Please See the above code sample @Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a try block inside of the try block you currently have for opening the dialog box. If you thwn leave the catch block empty then it will not display errors and just continue.

Option two is to place an empty else box under the if statement.

This is all assuming that the error is occurring in the above mentioned code

Comment: Sir Problem still remains.

Comment: Debug the code and see which line of code it throws the error on